# How to Encrypt and Decrypt a Android Studio and php same String?

Tags: java, php, android, encryption

How to encrypt and decrypt string in the same method use Android Studio in Java and PHP. I am using PHP this code.

PHP script code

```
<?
$plaintext = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$password = '112233';

$method = 'aes-256-cbc';

$key = substr(hash('SHA256', $password, true), 0, 32);

$iv = chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0);

$encrypted = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv));

$decrypted = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted), $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv);

 'plaintext=' . $plaintext . "\n";
 'cipher=' . $method . "\n";
echo 'encrypted to: ' . $encrypted . "\n";
echo 'decrypted to: ' . $decrypted . "\n\n";
?>
```

And Android Studio in java using this code.

Java code

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.security.MessageDigest;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class encryptanddecrypt extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText nameet,nameet2,etresult;
    Button encryptbt,decryptbt;
    String outputString;
    String AES = "AES",IV="112233";
    String secretKey;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_encryptanddecrypt);
        nameet=findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
        nameet2=findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName2);
        etresult=findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName3);
        encryptbt=findViewById(R.id.button6);
        decryptbt=findViewById(R.id.button7);

        encryptbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

outputString = encrypt(nameet.getText().toString(),nameet2.getText().toString());
etresult.setText(outputString);
} catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        decryptbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                   String outputStrings=decrypt(nameet.getText().toString(),nameet2.getText().toString());
                    etresult.setText(outputStrings);
                    Log.d("outputString",outputStrings);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private String decrypt(String outputString, String Password) throws Exception{
        SecretKeySpec key=generateKey(Password);
        Cipher c =Cipher.getInstance(AES);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,key);
        byte[] decodeValue = Base64.decode(outputString,Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decodeValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }
    private SecretKeySpec generateKey(String password) throws Exception{
        final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA256");
        byte[] bytes = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
        digest.update(bytes, 0,bytes.length);
        byte[] key = digest.digest();
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES");
        return secretKeySpec;
    }
private String encrypt(String Data, String Password) throws Exception{
        SecretKeySpec key=generateKey(Password);
        Log.d("checkkey", String.valueOf(key));
        Cipher c =Cipher.getInstance(AES);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue= Base64.encodeToString(encVal,Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.d("encryptedValue", encryptedValue);
        return encryptedValue;
    }
}
```

but some character is match and lasts some character is not matched please help please provide me php and android studio java code

Comment: Usually you do have a "reference" code that works and you like to transform it to another  framework - so what is your reference (Android/Java or PHP)? Some notes on your codes: the PHP is using AES in CBC mode (good) but a static IV (which makes the encryption **UNSECURE**). Your Java code is using AES in ECB mode that is **UNSECURE** in most use cases. Both: the usage of a (SHA-256) hash for key derivation is **UNSECURE**, please use a key derivation like PKKDF2.